# Going back from React 16 to 15

Tags: reactjs, npm

I don't know how to go back from React 16 to React 15.

I had the following lines in my package.json file,

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
  }
}
```

then I launched

```
npm install --save react@^16.0.0 react-dom@^16.0.0
```

which installed react 16.1.1. Then I saw a bug and wanted to go back, but, even with the following lines, which specify the exact version of react to use, react 16 continues to be used.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
  }
}
```

How do I go back to React 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After updating `dependencies` inside `package.json` you need to run `npm install` for the changes to take place.

Or if you want to do it all inside of command line you can do it like this:

```
npm install --save react@15.6.1 react-dom@15.6.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly update react version in `package.json`. Then, Delete folder `node_modules` from the project structure. And at last `npm install`.

Installation will fail if there is any version mismatch.
Please check for all the dependencies & then install those with the compatible version. Update those and run `npm install` again.

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git and you can roll back your commit, make sure you are in root of project directory then run this to find your changes: 

`git log`

for instance 0766c053 is the commit you want to revert:

`git revert --no-commit 0766c053..HEAD
rm -rf node_modules
npm i`

This will roll back to the exact package version you were before. If you don't use git you should do like Lina says:

`npm install --save react@15.6.1 react-dom@15.6.1`