# How to downgrade React version 17 to 16?

Tags: reactjs

How can I downgrade my React version from 17 to 16 as many of the React packages are not supported by React 17?

Comment: Downgrading is generally a bad practice you should try to persuade your team leader not to proceed (in the future your old react version might loose support become deprecated and insecure) suggest fixing incompatibilities and rather upgrade than downgrade.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you're using npm/yarn or another node package manager, dependency versions are listed in `package.json`.

Search for the `react` and `react-dom` packages under `dependencies` (or `devDependencies`) and replace their versions with `16.13.0`. Then run `npm install` or `yarn` or whatever package manager you're using. This should be enough to downgrade to React 16.

If you have packages not compatible with React 16, you might have to downgrade them, too.

Comment: and delete node_modules

Answer (score 9):

After updating dependencies inside package.json you need to run npm install for the changes to take place.

Or if you want to do it all inside of command line you can do it like this:

```bash
npm install --save react@16.14.0 react-dom@16.14.0
```

Source: [linasmnew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6061010/linasmnew)'s answer to [reactjs - Going back from React 16 to 15 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367166/going-back-from-react-16-to-15/47367305#47367305)

Comment: for the latest version you can just run npm install react@16 react-dom@16 and it will give you the most up to date minor version

Answer (score 2):

Because I needed `redux-devtools` as a package on an old project, I had to downgrade from React v17 to React v16. That's what i have done:

```
npm uninstall react-redux npm uninstall redux

npm install --save react@16.14.0 react-dom@16.14.0

npm install redux npm install react-redux

npm install --save-dev redux-devtools
```