# i am having an error while trying to install react-typical using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, next.js

this is the error
PS

```
C:\Users\aselemidivine\Desktop\portfolio_website-STARTER> npm i react-typical
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: portfolio_nextjs@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!   react-typical@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\aselemidivine\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aselemidivine\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-03T16_53_57_082Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Do you have react installed?

Comment: Yes I have react already installed. I had started with my project already and decided that I needed react-typical as well

Answer (score 2):

The peerDependencies of the react-typical package uses an older version of react.

1. You could downgrade your React package using the steps mentioned here [downgrade react version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109043/how-to-downgrade-react-version-17-to-16).
2. You can install it via this command `$ npm i react-typical --legacy-peer-deps`
   , to ignore peerDependencies and proceed with the installation.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I tried it just now and it worked.

Comment: rock on man! That's great!